# Поиск по дом элементам. Правильный ли подход?

Tags: javascript, html

Кусок кода вырван из контекста, но надеюсь будет понятен. Есть простая форма, и в ней есть `textarea`. Таких форм на странице неограниченное количество. Я пытаюсь работать с **ТЕКУЩЕЙ** формой через `e.target.form` и циклом пробегаюсь по дочерним элементам в поисках нужного, проверяя их классы, пока не совпадет с условием:

```js
const handleSaveTask = (e) => {
    const newTask = document.createElement('li');
    newTask.classList.add('task_item');

    for (let i = 0; i < e.target.form.children.length; i++) {
        if (e.target.form.children[i].classList.contains('js-task-area')) {
            newTask.innerHTML = e.target.form.children[i].value; // записываем в новый таск данные из текущей textarea
            e.target.form.previousElementSibling.appendChild(newTask); // ищем текущий тасклист и добавляем ему таск

            e.target.form.children[i].value = ''; //очищаем текущую textarea
        }
    }
    handleCheckArea(e);
};
```

**Вопрос**: насколько хороша такая практика? Можно ли ее улучшить?

Comment: Есть же querySelector https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector

Comment: не знал что можно юзать в связке с e.target :) спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```js
class Form {
  constructor(node) {
    this.node = node;

    if (!this.node) return;

    this.onTextarea = this.onTextarea.bind(this);

    this.textarea = this.node.querySelector('textarea');

    this.textarea.addEventListener('click', this.onTextarea, false);
  }

  onTextarea() {
    console.log(this.textarea.getAttribute('name'));
  }
}

[...document.querySelectorAll('[data-widget="form"]')]
  .forEach(form => new Form(form));
```

```html
<form data-widget="form" action="#"><textarea name="1" id="1" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></form>
<form data-widget="form" action="#"><textarea name="2" id="2" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></form>
<form data-widget="form" action="#"><textarea name="3" id="3" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></form>
```